# What is path of some file in resources?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, file-io, path

for example, how can i copy file to c:/ from my resources file ? 
i found similiar question in: [What is the file path, as a string, of a file in the application's resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123257/what-is-the-file-path-as-a-string-of-a-file-in-the-applications-resources) but it says "Error  2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'"

here is my current code, which is failed:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\", ctest.Properties.Resources.test);
```

test is the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binary file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\filename.bin", ctest.Properties.Resources.test);
```

For text file:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\filename.txt", ctest.Properties.Resources.test);
```

For image resource:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Resources.MyImageResource;
bitmap.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: oh wait, how can i move pictures(jpg) and (exe) files ?

Comment: The problem is not about extension `File.Copy` expects file names, while `ctest.Properties.Resources.test` is the `byte[]` content of your file in the resources.

Comment: You can't tell original file name from resource name. For example, if I add to the resources file named `New Text Document.txt` it will be added as resource name `New_Text_Document`. So you would need to use this code to save it with the original name `File.WriteAllText("C:\\New Text Document.txt", Properties.Resources.New_Text_Document)`

Comment: btw how can i change byte to string ? or how to get path of this file, not the file ? im trying to copy jpg file.

Comment: You can't get original path of the file as it is not persisted in the resources. Although Visual Studio knows original file name, compiled assembly does not.

Comment: well i guess there is no way to move file from resources then.(unless its txt or bin which isnt). not-related question: are there any way to get where file is installed and file-name ? so i can move my stuff to there. or move file to there.

Comment: @user683512 - You made incorrect conclusion. You can save image content and any binary content from your resources. You just need to specify file name. Just replace bin file extension in my example with exe. Also, I updated my asnwer with an example for images.

Comment: well, thank you. it works like a charm. however, it gives error called: "Access to the path  is denied" i mean i need to give permission to C:/ so i can write files in there etc. that was i can fix it for my own computer. but cant i make dialog box by windows appear ? so user will give permission to i write file there.